# React typescript: overridable component like mui?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type Props = {
  LabelComponent?: React.ElementType;
  title: string;
  (props of LabelComponent?)
}

const DefaultLabel:React.FC<{text:string}> = ({text}) => {
  return ...
}

const Paper: React.FC<Props> = ({LabelComponent=DefaultLabel, title, ...props}) => {
  return <div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <LabelComponent {...props} />
  </div>
}
```

I'd like something similar to [mui Box](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/box/)'s `component`.

How could I make the type hint to work?

So when no `LabelComponent` passed, `DefaultLabel` is used and when typing `<Paper ...`, `DefaultLabel`'s props are hinted.

And when other component passed, that component's props are hinted.